# Laravel Eloquent Select Group By : column "id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Tags: laravel, select, eloquent, group-by, laravel-7

**Grouping error: 7 ERROR:  column "id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function**

i want to show any id after I did the GroupBy multiple Column. even if the id is from first or from last

my code is :

```
$data = Book::select(
                  'id',
                  'tittle',
                  'writer',
                        )
                 ->groupBy('tittle','writer',)
                 ->paginate(10);
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove Id column from select function.

```
$data = Book::select(
                  'tittle',
                  'writer',
                        )
                 ->groupBy('tittle','writer',)
                 ->paginate(10);
```

Beacuse grouping is done when we have a duplicate record in our tables but id is primary key so remove it and than try again hope it will work

Comment: how you want to display your data share structure so i will help you